# Selecting all GameObjects in Unity

Tags: unity

I want to rotate all my GameObjects by 90 degrees. To do that I need to select all my GameObjects, how can I do so?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do this in code, or in the editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To loop over all GameObjects, use the following code:

JavaScript:

```
for(var gameObj : GameObject in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(GameObject))
{
    // modify gameObj.transform.rotation
}
```

C#:

```
foreach(GameObject gameObj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
{
    // modify gameObj.transform.rotation
}
```

Also see the manual for [FindObjectsOfType](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html).

Comment: `FindObjectsOfType` doesn't have a generic version, as far as I can tell.  So you have to do `FindObjectsOfType( typeof( GameObject ) ) as GameObject[]`.

Comment: Good to know; I'm not at a computer with Unity to test it.

Comment: It may just be a small micro-optimization, but I'd probably use a plain `for` loop over a `foreach` loop.