# How to search for a visible player?

Tags: unity, ai

I've an enemy static tank with a "rotable" cannon turret. 
I would like to rotate it in the player's direction .
How to implement it ?
I've thought something like

void Update {
    SearchForPlayer();
    RotateTurret();
}

I don't know how to implement a sort of radar function. 
Thanks

Comment: Philipp has already explained how rotation would work, but I wrote a piece of example code here that could work as a "radar": http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120431/how-to-get-the-closest-visible-object-from-my-player/120484#120484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html).

First you need to calculate the relative vector between player and tank. You do that by simply subtracting the position of the tank from the position of the player. Then you use Quaternion.LookRotatation to create a rotation into that direction.

```
Vector3 playerDirection = player.transform.position - tank.transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerDirection);
```

If you want the turret to turn immediately, you would simply assign that rotation to the `transform.rotation` of the tank turret. If you would prefer to move it slowly, use [`Quaternion.Lerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) to interpolate linearly between current and new position or [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) to rotate with a limited angular speed.